# How do I loop through this json array of unique, random keys?

Tags: php, json

Pretty simple, looping through each json object to get their child-values (they all have unique random keys, or this would be easier)

```
$Path = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://****.firebaseio.com/story.json"));

foreach( $Path as $obj ){
echo $obj->id . "<br>";

}
```

But doing it this way repeats them all for each key found.  Any idea how to echo each $obj->id only once?

Comment: You can use `array_rand()` for `$path` array But `$obj-id` may repeat.

Comment: What's the document structure?

Comment: structure: http://pastebin.com/1n1ZqDZ3

Answer (score 0):

its really hard to loop through properties of an object.  you know you can make json_decode return an associative array.  That would be a lot easier to loop through

just do

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$unique_ids = array();
foreach( $Path as $obj ){
    $id = $obj->id;
    if (!isset($unique_ids[$id])){
        $unique_ids[$id] = 1;
        echo $obj->id . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, `$isset` should be `isset`, what a shame.